# How to hide content in a txt file from direct url

Tags: .htaccess, file, security, url-rewriting

I'm working on a windows app which is reading a "authorized" domains list from a txt file with a web request from "domain.com/sub/txtfile"

I don't want people to see the content of the file when entering it directly in the browser. Is it possible to achieve this with some .htaccess hacks or something else?

Answer (score 0):

As your app is a client-side native Windows application, it's not possible to store any secret in the app itself that could be used for authentication. As the user has everything the Windows app may have, it impossible to authenticate the client as discussed many times here.

It also doesn't make much sense. Imagine it was somehow possible and file contents were only visible to your app. What would be the purpose? What if an attacker changed the hosts file on Windows to download the file from a rogue server? What if he used an intermediate proxy to inspect, change or replace contents? The latter is also possible with https, because the user has full control of the client, and can trust whatever certificate he wants.

You could authenticate the user though. An attacker can still see and modify downloaded file contents, but at least not anybody could download the file, only your authenticated users. But this means having a user database where the file is downloaded from, and implementing proper authentication. And it still doesn't solve the other problems.

In short, you can't protect a client-side application from a user that controls the whole client.